# Stop video play when leaving a jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

So I have a jquery mobile page with an html 5 video in it and that I want to be able to either stop playing and reset its self or just automatically pause the video. Would this be the correct javascript?

```
<script>

function restart() {
        var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
        video.currentTime = 0;}

    if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') != 'a28') { "restart"}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the pagehide , it gets called when the current active page gets hide / changed.

```
$(function(){
     $('#a28').live('pagehide',function(){
        //stop the video
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a loop, to check if the user is on the webpage. Store the time.

```
var lastSeen;
var loop = function (){
    lastSeen = Date.now();
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
};
loop();

var video = document.getElementById('Video1');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if(Date.now() - lastSeen > 100){
        this.pause();
    }
}, false);
```